# Send a keyup event to a child window without changing source of the child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two page like this

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var w=window.open("search.html","_blank");
        w.onload = function(){
            setTimeout(() => {
                $('#search', w.document).val("test");
                $('#search', w.document).trigger("keyup");
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

and search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="search">
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").keyup(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

When test.html load success, it open window search.html and set search value is test and send event keyup to it. But only set value can happen, keyup cannot send.
Please check for me :(

Comment: Why do you want to send values from `test.html` to `search.html` ? Is it okay to set the values in `search.html` instead of sending them from `test.html` ?

Comment: Because search.html has many version from many client, my customer waht to create an test.html and send some string to search.html for search some thing

Comment: No clear what you want to say. Can you tell what exactly what you are trying to implement in the real scenario ?

Comment: In my case: my customer want an page can handle many search.html. when user input some text in test.html, it send this string to input in search.html and raise keyup for search.

Comment: If *search.html* is not in your domain - you cannot. Well, besides asking the owner of that page to embed some scripts of yours. Or leverage the `event.origin` for [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) - if they use it at all.

Comment: @NguyênNgôDuy, show more of your actual code. In `test.html`, I see no way to input any text.

Comment: I think is best to send the value as an url parameter

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you was wrong closing it as a duplicate, that's a special case since the OP has no control over the child window's source. and it's resolved by me and the answer is accepted

Comment: @a Indeed. Reopened. Thank you for bringing it to my attention

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev seems like `search.html` *is* indeed on the same server (as stated by OP) and there's no restriction to Content-Security-Policy in place, nor X-Frame-Options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject the code into the child window;

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var w = window.open("search.html", "_blank");
        w.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $('#search', w.document).val("test");
                $(`<script>$("#search").trigger('keyup');<\/script>`).appendTo(w.document.head);
            }, 5000);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: But I can't edit search.html because my customer has many client and they can't edit all :(

Comment: @NguyênNgôDuy Nope, if search.html is not in your domain - there's not much you can do about it besides asking your customer to embed some scripts of yours.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan script injection works

Comment: @NguyênNgôDuy fixed, just inject the code into the child window